# Can't upgrade pip on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been having this problem for a couple of days now, I'm trying to deploy a django app in Elastic Beanstalk but every time I try to do it this particular error shows up:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-iHdpsP/pefile/ You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 21.1.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have read that by putting the command in the .ebextensions directory like:

```
container_commands:
  00_pip_upgrade:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip"
    ignoreErrors: false
```

that would do the job, but I'm still facing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

adding a file to my .ebextensions directory with this command fixed my issue:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/02a_upgrade_pip.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
      python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```